# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' при вводе данных в JSON

Tags: python, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть .txt файл с именами доменов. Мне нужно представить результат в формате JSON по типу

```
{"website.com":[{
    "hostname": "www.about.website.com"
    "ports": [{
        "80": "http"
        }],
    "hostname": "details.website.com"
    "ports": [{
        "80": "http",
        "443": "HTTPS"
    }]
},
{"web.ru": [{
    "hostname": "test.web.ru"
     }]
}]
}
```

Мне код выдаёт ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 71, in <module>
   'website.com':[{data}]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

указывая на 71-ую строку `'website.com': [{data}]` и в файле hosts.json не тот формат данных

```
  [
  {
    "hostname": "www.about.website.ru",
    "ports": [
      {
        "80": "http",
      }
    ]
  }
][
    "hostname": "details.website.com"
    "ports": [
    {
        "80": "http",
        "443": "HTTPS"
    }
  ]
][
  {
    "hostname": "test.web.ru"
  }
][
  {
    "hostname": "test.web.ru",
    "ports": [
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

Вот мой код

```
import json
import socket
from ping3 import ping

ports = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 43, 53, 80,
         115, 123, 143, 161, 179, 443, 445,
         514, 515, 993, 995, 1080, 1194,
         1433, 1723, 3128, 3268, 3306, 3389,
         5432, 5060, 5900, 8080, 10000]

services = [
    "FTP-DATA", "FTP", "SSH", "Telnet", "SMTP", "WHOIS", "DNS", "http", "SFTP", "NTP", "IMAP", "SNMP", "BGP", "HTTPS",
    "MICROSOFT-DS", "SYSLOG", "PRINTER", "IMAPS", "POP3S", "SOCKS", "OpenVPN", "SQL Server", "PPTP", "HTTP", "LDAP",
    "MySQL", "RDP", "PostgreSQL", "VNC", "Tomcat", "Webmin"]

numLines = sum(1 for line in open('../pythonProject/list_of_hosts.txt'))
hosts_website = []
hosts_web = []


def scan_and_write(host_name):
    host_ping = ping(host_name)

    if host_ping is not False:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        json_data = [{
            "hostname": f"{host_name}",
            "ports": [{}]
        }]
        try:
            a, s = 0, None
            for a in range(len(ports)):
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.01)
                result = s.connect_ex((ip, ports[a]))
                if result == 0:
                    json_data[0]["ports"][0][ports[a]] = services[a]
            with open("hosts.json", "a") as file:
                file.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
            if s is not None:
                s.close()
        except socket.error:
            print("Host not responding")
    else:
        json_data = [{
            "hostname": f"{host_name}"
        }]
        with open("hosts.json", "a") as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))


with open('../pythonProject/list_of_hosts.txt') as f:
    i = 0
    for i in range(numLines):
        line = f.readline()
        if 'website.com' in line:
            hosts_websute.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

with open('../pythonProject/list_of_hosts.txt') as f:
    i = 0
    for i in range(numLines):
        line = f.readline()
        if 'web' in line:
            hosts_web.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

with open('hosts.json', "w") as d:
    for i in range(len(hosts_website)):
        data = [scan_and_write(host_name=hosts_website[i])]
    json_main_website = [{
        'website.com': [{data}]
    }]
    d.write(json.dumps(json_main_website, indent=2))

    for i in range(len(hosts_web)):

        data = [scan_and_write(host_name=hosts_web[i])]
    json_main_lrmru = [{
        'web.ru': [{data}]
    }]
    d.write(json.dumps(json_main_web, indent=2))
```

Comment: У вас неправильная структура json, как минимум не хватает закрывающей скобки.

Comment: Что вам говорит ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 71, in <module> 'website.com': [{data}] TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

Я вам воспроизведу вашу ошибку на минимальном примере:

```py
data = [1, 2, 3]
x = [{data}]

----> 2 x = {data}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

А ещё понятнее вот так:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
x = {data}

----> 2 x = {data}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

У вас в `data` - некий список. А вот это `{data}` - **множество** из одного элемента, в которое вы пытаетесь превратить ваш список (как единый объект). Но множество можно сделать только из иммутабельных объектов, список к таковым не относится. Я, честно говоря, вообще не очень понимаю, что вы пытаетесь получить с помощью конструкции `[{data}]`.

Скорее всего вам эти скобки не нужны, а все нужные структуры вы должны сформировать внутри объекта `data` в готовом виде (и, возможно, вы это уже сделали, я детально не разбирался), тогда просто задайте этот объект `data` в качестве ключа словаря и всё:

```py
    json_main_website = [{
        'website.com': data
    }]
```

P.S. Хотя нет, у вас в целом явно всё неправильно:

```
    for i in range(len(hosts_website)):
        data = [scan_and_write(host_name=hosts_website[i])]
    json_main_website = [{
        'website.com': [{data}]
    }]
```

Здесь вы перетираете значение `data` в цикле. А функция `scan_and_write` у вас ничего не возвращает, то есть в `data` у вас будет тут значение `[None]`. Это помимо той ошибки, которую я выше разобрал.

Вам нужно сначала разобраться получше с **коллекциями** питона (словари и списки для начала) - как они создаются, как пополняются, как их вкладывать друг в друга. Как формировать коллекции в функции, возвращать их оттуда и получать. Тут весь код нужно переписывать, но если переписать его за вас, вы ничему не научитесь. Тут нет ничего сложного, нужно просто немного поразбираться и поучиться.